# Embedding multiple videos using oEmbed and Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, oembed

I'm trying to embed multiple videos to a web page using Vimeo's oEmbed. The idea is to simply enter the url in the CMS which will generate a div for each item containing the code below.

This javascript is doing what I want but only works with the first item. When I check the console there's only one response which contains the JSON metadata for the first item/video.

Probably this is not the best method but is getting the job done, all I need is to make it work for multiple items. Any ideas how can I do that?

Thank you

```
    <div class="vimeo-video" id="[[+ID]]-video"></div>
    <div class="vimeo-info" id="[[+ID]]-info"></div>
    <script>
        const getJSON = async url => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                if (!response.ok) // check if response worked (no 404 errors etc...)
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);

                const data = await response.json(); // get JSON from the response
                return data; // returns a promise, which resolves to this data value
            } catch (error) {
                return error;
            }
        }
        console.log("Fetching data...");
        getJSON("https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=[[+myVideoURL]]").then(data => {
            document.getElementById("[[+ID]]-video").innerHTML = data.html;
            document.getElementById("[[+ID]]-info").innerHTML = '<h2><a href="[[+myVideoURL]]" target="_blank">' + data.title + '</a></h2>' + data.description;
            console.log(data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody with basic javascript skills like me goes through something similar. The problem was a rookie's mistake, I had to use `var` instead of `const`.

The reason is because `var` variables can be updated and re-declared but const variables can neither be updated nor re-declared. So here's the working code:

```
var getJSON = async (url) => {
  try {
    var response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok)
      // check if response worked (no 404 errors etc...)
      throw new Error(response.statusText);

    var data = await response.json(); // get JSON from the response
    return data; // returns a promise, which resolves to this data value
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```